# computed locals from variable in terraform v12 syntax

Tags: terraform

I am trying to create a computed local from a variable.
Is this syntax correct?
If I call `for_each = locals.db_services` in a resource, will `terraform` automatically add it to the dependency graph?

```
variable "services" {
    type = list(object)
}

locals {
    db_services = {
        for service in var.services:
        service.name => service
        if index(lookup(service, "storage", []), "postgres") > 0 && service.cluster == "service"
    }
}

resource "aws_ecs_task_definition" "rds_dump_task" {
  for_each = local.db_services

  family                = format("rds-dump-task-%s-%s", each.value.name, var.environment)
  container_definitions = data.template_file.container_definition[each.key].rendered
  task_role_arn         = format("arn:aws:iam::%s:role/%s-ecs-task-%s",
    var.account_id,
    each.value.name,
    var.environment
  )
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The syntax works!
Also, var.services is stored in .json.tf file format and it works very nicely.